# Skyscraper puzzle algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, puzzle

I'm writing an algorithm to solve [skyscrapers puzzles](http://www.puzzlemix.com/Skyscraper):

> Skyscraper puzzles combine the row and column constraints of Sudoku with external clue values that re-imagine each row or column of numbers as a road full of skyscrapers of varying height. Higher numbers represent higher buildings.
>
> To solve a Skyscraper puzzle you must place 1 to 5, or 1 to whatever the size of the puzzle is, once each into every row and column, while also solving each of the given skyscraper clues.
>
> To understand Skyscraper puzzles, you must imagine that each value you place into the grid represents a skyscraper of that number of floors. So a 1 is a 1-floor skyscraper, while a 4 is a 4-floor skyscraper. Now imagine that you go and stand outside the grid where one of the clue numbers is and look back into the grid. That clue number tells you how many skyscrapers you can see from that point, looking only along the row or column where the clue is, and from the point of view of the clue. Taller buildings always obscure lower buildings, so in other words higher numbers always conceal lower numbers.

All the basic techniques are implemented and working, but I've realized that with bigger puzzles (5x5>) I need some sort of recursive algorithm. I found a decent working [python script](http://pastebin.com/wxuiBt57), but I'm not really following what it actually does beyond solving basic clues.

Does anyone know the proper way of solving these puzzles or can anyone reveal the essentials in the code above?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You're being downvoted because you haven't shown any effort in trying to solve the puzzle yourself. Read my answer, try my suggestions, and come back here when you've done some work on your own.

Comment: @misha: I've tried a lot of things. After the basic clues have been solved (clues of n and clues of 1) and if I'm really unlucky only a couple of squares are filled. Then I've tried to fill each cell making sure they only appeare once in every row and column. But the thing is - how can I verify the clue restraint when the puzzle isn't even halfway done? I'm not asking for code here, just a tip or two on how to "wrap my mind" around this. And I really don't think brute forcing is the way to go. =)

Comment: Regarding your existing work, show your code (including inputs, expectations and actual results) or it didn't happen :) Regarding verifying incomplete boards: do you really need a complete board the time? You can check rows/columns independently - if one of them violates the constraint, then you don't need to bother completing that board (in other words, backtrack and try something else). Finally, regarding brute force: yes, it is rarely the way to go, but it's always better than no way at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Misha showed you the brute-force way. A much faster recursive algorithm can be made based on [constraint propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction). Peter Norvig (head of Google Research) wrote an [excellent article](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) about how to use this technique to solve Sudoku with python. Read it and try to understand every detail, you will learn a lot, guaranteed. Since the skyscraper puzzle has a lot in common with Sudoku (without the 3X3 blocks, but with some extra constraints given by the numbers on the edge), you could probably steal a lot of his code.

You start, as with Sudoku, where each field has a list of all the possible numbers from 1..N. After that, you look at one horizontal/vertical line or edge clue at a time and remove illegal options. E.g. in a 5x5 case, an edge of 3 excludes 5 from the first two and 4 from the first squares. The constraint propagation should do the rest. Keep looping over edge constraints until they are fulfilled or you get stuck after cycling through all constraints. As shown by Norvig, you then start guessing and remove numbers in case of a contradiction.

In case of Sudoku, a given clue has to be processed only once, since once you assign a single number to one square (you remove all the other possibilities), all the information of the clue has been used. With the skyscrapers, however, you might have to apply a given clue several times until it is totally satisfied (e.g. when the complete line is solved).

Comment: Thanks! I've read about constraint propagation. What I don't get is how I can use it correctly when, like I said, the puzzle is almost empty. Where do I "start"? Say I start out with filling up cells so that the first constraint is fulfilled. But how can I now go back and rearrange the numbers so they fulfill the clue constraint as well?

Answer (score 5):

If you're desperate, you can brute-force the puzzle. I usually do this as a first step to become familiar with the puzzle. Basically, you need to populate `NxN` squares with integers from 1 to N inclusive, following the following constraints:

- Each integer appears in every row exactly once
- Each integer appears in every column exactly once
- The row "clues" are satisfied
- The column "clues" are satisfied

The brute force solution would work like this. First, represent the board as a 2D array of integers. Then write a function `is_valid_solution` that returns True if the board satisfies the above constraints, and False otherwise. This part is relatively easy to do in `O(N^2)`.

Finally, iterate over the possible board permutations, and call `is_valid_solution` for each permutation.  When that returns True, you've found a solution.  There are a total of `N^(NxN)`  possible arrangements, so your complete solution will be `O(N^(NxN))`.  You can do better by using the above constraints for reducing the search space.

The above method will take a relatively long while to run (`O(N^(NxN))` is pretty horrible for an algorithm), but you'll (eventually) get a solution. When you've got that working, try to think of a better way to to it; if you get stuck, then come back here.

**EDIT**

A slightly better alternative to the above would be to perform a search (e.g. depth-first) starting with an empty board. At each iteration of the search, you'd populate one cell of the table with a number (while not violating any of the constraints). Once you happen to fill up the board, you're done.

Here's pseudo-code for a recursive brute-force depth-first search. The search will be `NxN` nodes deep, and the branching factor at each node is at most `N`. This means you will need to examine at most `1 + N + N^2 + ... + N^(N-1)` or `(N^N-1)/(N-1)` nodes. For each of these nodes, you need to call `is_valid_board` which is O(N^2) in the worst case (when the board is full).

```
def fill_square(board, row, column):
  if row == column == N-1: # the board is full, we're done
    print board
    return
  next_row, next_col = calculate_next_position(row, col)
  for value in range(1, N+1):
    next_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    next_board[row][col] = value
    if is_valid_board(next_board):
      fill_square(next_board, next_row, next_col)

board = initialize_board()
fill_square(board, 0, 0)
```

The function `calculate_next_position` selects the next square to fill. The easiest way to do this is just a scanline traversal of the board. A smarter way would be to fill rows and columns alternately.

Comment: This is definitely a valid brute force method, but I thought the OP already had one of those: "*...the basic techniques are implemented and working, but I've realized that with bigger puzzles...*". Not that he posted it, but this doesn't really answer the problem, which I read as "how do I look at this in a recursive way?"

Comment: @Geobits: if you have a recursive solution, feel free to include it in your answer :) I couldn't come up with one in the few minutes I had to think about the problem.

Comment: @misha How do you get to the number of `N^3` possible permutations? I can see a very naive upper limit of `N^(NxN)` if you can choose each square from 1..N independent of the others. Slightly better would be `(N!)^N`, if you permute the sequence 1..N for every row. I would not be surprised if you can get it down to N^3 or so with some smart permutation algorithm, I just do not see how to prove that easily.

Comment: My bad, `N^(NxN)` was what I was thinking about. Thanks for pointing it out. And yes, that's the dumbest possible way to think about it; you could definitely reduce it by considering the constraints.

Comment: Just to give some numbers: for `N=5`, the naive algorithm gives `N^(N*N) = 3e17` permutations! The slightly better way of permuting every row gives `(N!)^N = 2.5e10` permutations. The best algorithm I could imagine is to alternatively permute a row and a column of all remaining possibilities. This gives 
`N! * ((N-1)!)^2 * ((N-2)!)^2 * ... * 2!^2  = 1e7` permutations. There is still some redundancy remaining, but for sure the real number is bigger than `N^3 = 125`.

Comment: A search would work better (see my updated answer). The max branch length would be `N*N` (one level for each square), so a DFS is possible. The branching factor would be N for each level. You'd have to look at a total of `1 + N + N^2 + N^3 + ... + N^(N-1)` or `(N^N-1)/(N-1)` nodes. For N=5, this is equal to 781 nodes (definitely doable).  You could reduce it further by pruning.

Comment: You are going `N*N` levels deep, so shouldn't that be again `... + N^(N*N-1)` or so? And I guess `value == i` in your example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It ends up being the same number as above (for N=5, 3.7e17). This is huge, but it doesn't take into account that the branching factor decreases with branch length.