# Scala - Skyscraper puzzle

Tags: algorithm, scala, puzzle

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to solve a skyscraper puzzle (http://www.brainbashers.com/skyscrapershelp.asp) in any given NxN. I have tried to make a brute-force solution, but since I've ran it it doesn't seem to be finishing any time soon (been running for an hour now without the last cell of the board updating past "1"). I've been looking into algorithms to solve the puzzle in a more efficient way, but I don't really understand how it works. I have set up a program that manages to:

1) test for hints with the value of the size of the puzzle (e.g. 5 in a 5x5 puzzle), which means the neighbouring row has to go from 1 in the field next to the hint, incrementing by 1 up to the size of the puzzle (5 in the earlier example, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

2) test for hints with the value 1, which means that the neighbouring field has to be of the max size of the puzzle (5 in the earlier example). But after this, I don't really know where to go next with my code. I know how to work if I solve a puzzle of a specific size (e.g. 4x4), but the problem is developing one for a NxN puzzle... I found this: [Skyscraper puzzle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872553/skyscraper-puzzle-algorithm)
but I didn't really understand the answers provided there.
I've also found this: http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Skyscrapers-Puzzle
but it's a specific example, and I don't really understand how to convert it into a NxN algorithm.

I can't post more than two links, so I will post the link to my code (both the brute-force solution and as far as I've come in the algorithm one) as a comment to this question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Here's my brute-force solution (not 100% sure if it works, though, as I never get to really test if it works due to how long it takes to run): http://pastebin.com/jzbzGAwN

This is as far as I've come with the algorithm-solution: http://pastebin.com/HFc9HxKz
as you can see I have an "updateTrueValues" function which processes the board and tries to trim down the possible values for the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that will work:

1) For your grid size, generate an array of all permutations of the numbers.  For instance in a 4x4, you'd have [1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134, 2143, 2314, 2341, etc]

2) Then for each of those, compute the visible skyscrapers from the left and the right.
[[1234, 4, 1], [1243, 3, 2], [1324, 3, 1], ...

3) For each row of your puzzle, generate the list of skyscrapers that will work by selecting those rows from step 2 that match the numbers on the left and right of your puzzle.

4) So, now you might have 1 that works for row 1, 3 that work for row 2, 2 that work for row 3 and 2 that work for row 4.  Here comes the brute force part.  You want to try all combinations of each of those and test to see if they satisfy the top and bottom numbers.  For my example, you'd have to test 1*3*2*2 = 12 combinations to find the one that works.  You'd also want to verify that each column contains each number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your concept/logic and how it would work, but I don't really know how to implement it. especially in Scala. To start with 1), I think I've figured out how to print out all permutations of an array of ints from 0 to N (something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218019/generating-permutations-of-an-int-array-using-java-erro), but creating a new array with all permutations is beyond what I can do at the moment.