# Waffle Stacking Puzzle Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, puzzle

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:
http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw16/problems/2013ProblemSetFinalPost.pdf
go to problem number 20.  It is called Waffle Stacking.

> You have a 5x5 square grid. On each square of the grid you can build a stack of
>   waffles, with its height ranging from 1 to 5. Around the edge of the grid are some
>   numeric clues. Your task is to build a stack of waffles on every square, in such a
>   way that:
>    • Each row contains every possible height of the waffle stack once
>    • Each column contains every possible height of the waffle stack once
>    • Each numeric clue describes the number of waffle stacks that can be
>   seen if you look into the row or column from that direction, assuming
>   that shorter waffle stacks are hidden behind taller ones. For example, a
>   clue marked ‘5’ indicates that the five waffle stacks must appear in increasing
>   order (otherwise you would not be able to see all five waffle
>   stacks), whereas a clue marked ‘1’ indicates that the tallest waffle stack (the one marked 5) must
>   come first.
>
> Input:
>   [image]
>
> Output:
>   [image]
>
> The first line of input shows the clues for the top of each column. The next 5 lines of input show the clues for the left and right sides of the diagram for each row. The final line of input shows the clues for the bottom of each column.
>   `2 2 3 2 1`
>   `4 1`
>   `1 4`
>   `3 2`
>   `2 2`
>   `3 2`
>   `3 2 1 3 4`
>   Your program should print the 5x5 grid, with a space between each square in a row.
>   `1 3 2 4 5`
>   `5 2 4 3 1`
>   `2 1 3 5 4`
>   `4 5 1 2 3`
>   `3 4 5 1 2`

I have started by saying that if there is a 1, the 5 must be right next to it, so I immediately place the 5 in a solution grid.  After that, I am stuck!  I have tried brute force, but it takes too long to be practical in a contest setting.

Is there any viable solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I recognize those screenshots! That's Simon Tatham's [Towers](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/java/towers.html) game. Playing with the actual game may give you some ideas :-)

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the post. External links are dangerous and might go dead in the future, rendering this Q&A unusefil for future visitors

Comment: @eKek0 "Is there any viable solution to this problem?" isn't a Code Golf question. Do you know what Code Golf is?

Comment: I think brute-force is indeed the solution given the tiny constraints. You just need to do better pruning.

Comment: I agree with @NiklasB. The solution to this puzzle is always a [latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), and there are only 161280 latin squares of size 5. You can quickly narrow it down further, since you always know the exact location of at least two of the tallest stacks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skyscraper puzzle algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872553/skyscraper-puzzle-algorithm), just replace skyscraper with waffle.

Comment: It can get easily solved using genetic algorithms, is it in your interest to I post an answer for you?

Comment: @Dukeling As it was stated originally, it likely was.